# The selected user was not found in the privilege table error occurred during the user creation in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

When i am trying to create a new user in my PhpMyAdmin.
It says user is created, but after that this error is coming:

> The selected user was not found in the privilege table

and I am not able to see all my created users in database.
Please help me to get out of it :).

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted a row from the mysql table you need to run FLUSH PRIVILEGES, if not the user hasn’t really been removed.

Try `flush privileges;` under the SQL tab in PhpMyAdmin.